# get value from stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

This is my SP:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=FUNCTION `test`(p_begin varchar(10),p_end varchar(10),p_code varchar(2)) RETURNS varchar(10) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_ADA VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE V_LAST VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE V_NIK  VARCHAR(8);

    select NIK INTO V_NIK from absen where join_date >= p_begin and join_date<= p_end AND company_id=p_code ORDER BY NIK DESC LIMIT 1 ;

    SET V_NIK=V_NIK+1;
    return V_NIK;
END
```

I am trying to get the return value with php:

```
$query=$this->db->query("select test(\"$begin\",\"$end\", \"$code\")")->result();

    var_dump($query);
    die;
```

The result is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (1) { ["test("2007-01-01","2007-12-31", "1")"]=> string(7) "118" } }
```

My problem is that I want to get the value from stored procedure ("118") and I don't know how to change the object into a string.

Comment: Is that possible to rewrite your query as `"SELECT test('$begin', '$end', '$code') AS result"`? Also, isn't that vulnerable to SQL injections?

Comment: @raina77ow i get this object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#19 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(31) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(43) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["row_data"]=> NULL }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("select test(\"$begin\",\"$end\", \"$code\")")->result();

// Cast object to array (also you can try get_object_vars() to do that)
$query = (array)$query[0];

// Get the last value from array (it the only on so it is OK)
echo end($query);
```

Perhaps will help..

Comment: Oh, I think he is gone away enjoying his solution)

Comment: @raina77ow i want to accept it from 3 minutes ago but, i have to wait :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to send the object as text to somewhere else (database, Javascript code), you have a choice of serialize, json_encode, XML conversion, and many more, depending on your exact situation.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: "I don't know how to change the object into a string."....This depends on the requirement. Why would he need to change the object to a string ?